# How to use "And" operator using selenium webdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a login button and want to identify it using xpath and id. But both the `xpath` and `id` are dynamically changing. Please advise on how to do it.

The Xpath and ID keep changing as below for login button and i am not able to find any common element to find it:

**Xpath** : .//*[@id='uO4Qo']
**ID** : uO4Qo

**Xpath** : .//*[@id='tP5Qo']
**ID** : tP5Qo

**Xpath** : .//*[@id='vVBPn']
**ID** : vVBPn

Comment: Did you try CSS path, perhaps nth-child?

Comment: You may show the html. I am afraid that you can use both xpath and id as locators to identify.

Comment: Those `xpath` are using the id attribute, you are not looking for another locator when using them.

Comment: How can i use CSS or html for identity?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium IDE to create your script, the target field is a dropdown, displaying all the possible options to identify your specified button. If the options CSS, name or anything else are not available, it means that these things are not present on your page. Perhaps is xpath:position an option in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, use login button text in place of LoginButtonText:

```
driver.findElement(By.LinkText("LoginButtonText")).click();
```